# Von Mises mixtures: What is the maximum kappa value?

Tags: mixture-distribution, cohens-kappa, circular-statistics

I have an R script that is estimating the concentration parameters (kappa) for Von Mises mixtures. This script is giving me values of kappa that are 60, 100 e.c.t. I was expecting kappa to be less than 10. What is the maximum value of kappa for Von Mises mixtures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem copy and paste the 'r8_error_f' script found here, http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/prob/r8_error_f.m, into a matlab script and save it under the correct name. Then just make sure it’s in the same folder as the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed maximum. Data gets more concentrated as kappa increases. In the limit, with $\kappa \rightarrow \infty$, the density will tend to a point mass distribution.

60 is not a value to be too surprised about if the data lies in a small arc.

Comment: Thanks Kees for the answer. I am using a MATLAB function to calculate the inverse Von Mises CDF & the function will not work if Kappa is greater than 10. Do you have any Idea why this might be?

Comment: I am using the following code: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt%20/m_src/prob/von_mises_cdf_inv.m

Comment: If I try to run this code for von_mises_cdf_inv(0.5, 0, 11) MATLAB gives me the following error: 
"Undefined function 'r8_error_f' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in von_mises_cdf (line 126)
    erfx = r8_error_f ( arg );

Error in von_mises_cdf_inv (line 60)
    cdf3 = von_mises_cdf ( x3, a, b );"

Comment: As you note below, this error has to do with MATLAB syntax, and likely not the fact that the function does not work for $\kappa > 10$.